# DB design. Using Status table

Tags: java, sql, database, spring-boot

I was told that storing statuses as a table is better than creating Enums for my statuses. So I created a table for CompliantStatus. My question is where to insert these statuses and how to use them in my services classes. When I was using enums I was simply accesing the class Ex: Status.(myStatus). But how can I do this using status entity?

```
@Table
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter

public class ComplaintStatus extends LookupEntity{

}



@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class LookupEntity extends BaseEntity{

    @Column
    private String nameAr;

    @Column
    private String nameEn;

    @Column
    private Long code;
}
```

Comment: _I was told that storing statuses as a table is better than creating Enums_ Find out **why**  they said that.  Referential integrity in a relational DB is a good thing, but that doesn't mean the app should not use an enum.

Comment: enums are for integrity throughout the whole code without any relation to a seperate table and is such not easy to tamper with. I would actually keep the enums. Also they get detected by the autocomplete by most IDE's and such are easier to code with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating the statuses in your database you need to use a DB change management framework, such as Liquibase.

And when you define the status column in another data object you can do something like:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false) 
@JoinColumn(name = "statusid", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private ComplaintStatus status;
```

Comment: But, how I can assign a complaint to a status? 
When I was using enums I would simply do complaint.setStatus(Status.processing_the_complaint)

If I want to use statuses stored in a table what should I do?

Comment: You need an instance of ComplaintStatus for the assignment. And there are options here.
For example, you could implement a lookup method (maybe backed by a cache), then setting a status would be something like:
complaint.setStatus(ComplaintStatus.lookup('processing'))
You could also annotate the status field with the @Convert (instead of @JoinColumn) and supply a converter class that will convert between ComplaintStatus and the database status_id field (using a getter and the same lookup method).